# Jboss server keeps starting up

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jboss5.x

I have configured Jboss 5.1 in the eclipse environment.

The problem comes when I start the server,in the console it shows as JBoss server has started in xx min and xx seconds, however it still keeps showing that the jboss server is starting in eclipse server window.
It finally times out and stops the server based on the server timeout for startup of Jboss.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem. Solved!

There are couple of options that you might want to try out.

- Make sure your jobss is using JDK instead of JRE in eclipse. To do that make sure in your eclipse, windows ->> preferences ->> java ->> installed JREs ->> select JDK.
- If you have changed the port, make sure eclipse is using the same port. you can always check it inside Jboss folder ->> standalone ->> configuration ->> standalone.xml file. scroll down. you will get all the port details.
- Last one that I did and solved my problem. in your eclipse, double click on Jboss, select "web port" as a Startup Poller, uncheck the management port option "detect from local runtime". Restart the server. it should work.

There is a nice explanation with snapshots. you can always check it out. [click here](https://developer.jboss.org/en/tools/blog/2011/11/24/jboss-as-71-beta1-with-jboss-tools--use-web-port-poller)

Answer (score 0):

Before starting JBoss double click on the configuration in Server window. JBoss configuration should be opened. Look for the timeouts section - adjust it as needed (5 minutes should be enough even if you deploy large applications). Extend both start and stop timeout. If JBoss is not stopped properly then you will need to kill Java process from Task Manager). Don't forget to save modified configuration (Ctrl S).

Answer (score 0):

On the topic of jboss/wildfly keeping strating up.

Please be aware that on the most recent version of the wilfly/jboss eclipse plugin an issue was introduced with the deployment scanners.

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-10629

The plugin from eclipse will automatically add deployment scanners to your standalone.xml which cause an inifine deploy issue to take place.

When double cliking on the server, you can disable the plugin from modifying your standalone.xml with these deployment scanners.